# render error while i wanted to get data from server

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a code that is a component in react which is used Redux to get data from server. this is my very simple component:

```
class Survey extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getSurvey(this.props.match.params.uuid);
  }

  render() {
    const { survey } = this.props;
    const { name } = survey; // << *********** ERROR **********

    return (
      <Hoc>
        <Card title="Name" bordered={false} style={{ width: 300 }}>
          <p>Card content</p>
          <p>Card content</p>
          <p>Card content</p>
        </Card>
      </Hoc>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    survey: state.survey.currentSurvey
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getSurvey: uuid => dispatch(surveyGetData(uuid))
  };
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Survey)
);
```

But when i've used this component it gave me an error which said "survey" is null. i tackled about this issue and i've found out when my getSurvey function in componentWillMount run my render method execute before it goes trough redux action to do process of changing the state and pass it to my component to render and there is my problem.

is there any better way to get through this problem without using a big condition?

Answer (score 2):

Your default value for survey probably is null. So when the component renders the first time 'survey' in `const { survey } = this.props;` is null. The request to get the survey is async so the response might/will come after the initial render.

One solution might be to have a 'loading' flag on your state. While true you can show a loader when rendering the component. You can set the flag true when you fire the request to get the survey and back to false if the request has finished. At that point the survey should be set and you can render your component as you wish. Of course the request response must be succesfull.

Comment: yes initial state of the survey is null i myself assigned it in my reducer because i wanted to get my data from server before my component want to be render

Comment: So, there you have it.

Comment: thank you this is good solution. but the confusing part for me is that is there any way to force getting data before calling render function . its interesting i have a source file that uses exact the same thing i've done without geting to this problem. Connect component delivered props before render function run.

Comment: Do you think this is a typical issue i came across in using react and redux together?

Comment: It's a common pattern, yes.You could also take a look at React Suspense

Answer (score 0):

Its because your `const { survey } = this.props;` is null. For handling this you need some kind of check i.e

```
const { survey } = this.props;
if(!survey) return null;//ensure component does not render if survey not found    
const { name } = survey; //It means we find survey here we can move for next logic
```